# The operation couldn't be completed (Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=1718449215) AVPlayer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

Getting "**The operation couldn't be completed (Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=1718449215)"** or **"Cannot decode"** error when I'm trying to play next video from video list using AVPlayer. If I restart my app again then video is playing where I was getting error (getting status = failed from "**AVPlayerItem**") but another video is unable to play without restart the app while I'm releasing all AVPlayer instance before playing next video.

```
private var playerItemObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? {
    willSet {
        /// Remove any previous KVO observer.
        guard let playerItemObserver = playerItemObserver else {return }
        playerItemObserver.invalidate()
    }
    
    didSet {
        playerItemObserver = playerItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.status, options: [.new, .initial]) { [weak self] (item, _) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            
            if item.status == .readyToPlay {
                // Ready to Play Video
            } else if item.status == .failed {
                // Unable to play video
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(strongSelf, selector: #selector(strongSelf.failedToPlayToEndTime), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: item)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Geeting error and expecting everytime status == .readyToPlay while play each video without restart the app.